# RXJS's Subject inside Function

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, subject-observer

Please, I need help with my code that does not work:

```
this.howToUseObservables().subscribe(ress => alert('in app ' + ress));
```

Why `testSubject.next('test');` does not fire at all?
thanks

```
howToUseObservables(): Subject<any> {
const testSubject: Subject<any> = new Subject();
testSubject.next('test');
return testSubject;
}

this.howToUseObservables().subscribe(ress => alert('in app ' +ress));
```

Comment: Appears you're calling `next('test')` before subscription so it doesn't know anything about previous messages. You can try `BehaviorSubject`

Comment: you are right I used BehaviorSubject instead and worked fine 
thanks for your help :)